# How to remove read-only routing URL

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups

How can I remove the Read-Only Routing URL in an availability group.

I have set the Read-Only routing URL and I'm trying to get it back to how it was before my test and I can't find a way to remove those URL.

I tried with :
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]
 MODIFY REPLICA ON
N'COMPUTER01' WITH
(SECONDARY_ROLE (READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N''));
but SQL does not allow an empty value here.

Thank you for you precious help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method for deleting a read only routing URL for a given replica. Your only options are to change the URL to something else (just putting a different URL in the `READ_ONLY_ROUTING_URL = N'tcp://newRoutingString'` or dropping the replica entirely from the AG and putting it back in again (less than ideal I know).

If you adjust the replica to `SECONDARY_ROLE(ALLOW_CONNECTIONS = NONE)` then you can at least prevent any potential attempts to hit that URL.